# HTML markup to image in Angular 2

Tags: html, image, angular, html5-canvas

can any one tell me how to convert html markup to an image and save it. i tried researching on google but i did not find anything. it would be great if you could provide me any resource or article to achieve the functionality. OR is it possible to take a screen shot of the rendered html on the browser and save it as an image? please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that using an JavaScript library called **[html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)**. This library will allow you to take screenshots of a webpage.

The screenshots are usually saved as a canvas element, which you can easily convert to an image later on.

Refer [here](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) to learn more about the library and the use cases.